# изменение backgroundPosition элемента по скроллу документа

Tags: javascript

задача - по скроллу должна изменяться горизонтальная координата фона в одном из блоков. по скроллу вниз уменьшаться, по скроллу вверх увеличиваться. для начала я попыталась просто связать изменение backgroundPosition с количеством проскролленных пикселей:

```
var pixelsFromTop = 0;
var xValue = 50;
var movingClouds = document.querySelector('.header-clouds');

function scrollInit() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    pixelsFromTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    xValue = xValue - pixelsFromTop;
    movingClouds.style.backgroundPosition = 'xValue + "%" + " " + "0%"';
    console.log(xValue);
  });
}

scrollInit();
```

значение xValue по скроллу изменяется, значение положения фона - нет. почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pixelsFromTop = 0;
var xValue = 50;
var movingClouds = document.querySelector('.header-clouds');

function scrollInit() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    pixelsFromTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    xValue = xValue - pixelsFromTop;
    movingClouds.style.backgroundPosition = xValue + '"%" + " " + "0%"';
    console.log(xValue);
  });
}

scrollInit();
```

Конкретнее `style.backgroundPosition = xValue` `xValue` вынести за кавычку

Comment: ааа, внутри кавычек оно просто приводится к строке. спасибо! на самом деле сработал вариант вообще без внешних кавычек, xValue + "%" + " " + "0%";